# call back for javascript animation

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-animate

I have a java script animation for scrolling unto to the top of a page smoothly.At the end of animation I have a .focus() function to focus on a form field. The focus is causing some jerkiness. Upon researching I found out I can fix by having a call back for animation and having the focus in that. I am not sure how to do that. Any help is much appreciated.

```
  $(".scroll").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //calculate destination place
     var dest=0;
     if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
          dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
     }else{
          dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
     }
     //go to destination
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');

     $('input#Name_First').focus();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1kbph7q3/

Comment: `$(".scroll")` matches nothing in your jsFiddle.

Comment: How about reading the jQuery documentation? Not only does it describe the function signature (i.e. which arguments the function accepts), but it also has examples which show you how to add a callback. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the comments on your question are correct.

Heres a working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/got29e9v/1/

1. The first error was that the anchor link need the class of `.scroll`.
2. Also the JS fiddle wasn't using JQuery, your JavaScript was trying to use it.
3. I've added a callback function on the animate method. This is called when the animation completes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree.  While duplicating my code on fiddle I might have missed on adding the class.My apologies.

Your code snipper helped. Thank you very much.